# What am I not getting about foreach loops?

Tags: perl, loops, for-loop, foreach

It was always my understanding that

```
foreach (@arr)
{
    ....
}
```

and

```
for(my $i=0; $i<@arr; $i++)
{
    .....
}
```

were functionally equivalent. 
However, in all of my code, whenever I use a `foreach` loop I run into problems that get fixed when I change to a `for` loop. It always has to do with comparing the values of two things, usually with nested loops.

Here is an example:

```
for(my $i=0; $i<@files; $i++)
{
    my $sel;
    foreach (@selected)
    {
        if(files[$i] eq selected[$_])
        {
            $selected='selected';
        }
    }
    <option value=$Files[$i] $sel>$files[$i]</option>
}
```

The above code falls between select tags in a cgi program. 
Basically I am editing the contents of a select box according to user specifications.
But after they add or delete choices I want the choices that were origionally selected to remain selected.

The above code is supposed to accomplish this when reassembling the select on the next form. However, with the `foreach` version it only gets the first choice that's selected and skips the rest. If I switch it to a 3 part `for` loop, without changing anything else, it will work as intended.

This is only a recent example, so clearly I am missing something here, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Ask question again after `use warnings;`

Comment: Thanks Toby, I probably should have inferred that earlier, that's actually really convenient.

Comment: `for (my $i=0; $i<@arr; $i++)` is functionally equivalent to `for my $i (0..$#arr)`, not `for my $ele (@#arr)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348505/c-style-loops-vs-perl-loops has some good discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume that `@files` is a list of filenames.

In the following code, `$i` is the array *index* (i.e. it's an integer):

```
for (my $i=0; $i<@files; $i++) { ... }
```

In the following code, `$i` is set to each array *item* in turn (i.e. it's a filename):

```
foreach my $i (@files) { ... }
```

So for example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = (
   'foo.txt',
   'bar.txt',
   'baz.txt',
);

print "for...\n";
for (my $i=0; $i<@files; $i++) {
   print "\$i is $i.\n";
}

print "foreach...\n";
foreach my $i (@files) {
   print "\$i is $i.\n";
}
```

Produces the following output:

```
for...
$i is 0.
$i is 1.
$i is 2.
foreach...
$i is foo.txt.
$i is bar.txt.
$i is baz.txt.
```

`foreach` loops are generally preferred for looping through arrays to avoid accidental off-by-one errors caused by things like `for (my $i=1;...;...)` or `for (my $i=0;$i<=@arr;...)`.

That said, `for` and `foreach` are actually implemented as synonyms in Perl, so the following script produces identical output to my previous example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files = (
   'foo.txt',
   'bar.txt',
   'baz.txt',
);

print "for...\n";
foreach (my $i=0; $i<@files; $i++) {
   print "\$i is $i.\n";
}

print "foreach...\n";
for my $i (@files) {
   print "\$i is $i.\n";
}
```

It it simply customary to refer to the second type of loop as a `foreach` loop, even if the source code uses the keyword `for` to perform the loop (as has become quite common).

Comment: Your perception that `for` and `foreach` have different implications isn't correct, however I have hacked your answer rather more than I intended. Please revert it to the original if you feel I have corrupted what you intended to say