# C-style loops vs Perl loops (in Perl)

Tags: perl, for-loop, iteration

I feel like there is something I don't get about perl's looping mechanism.

It was my understanding that

```
for my $j (0 .. $#arr){...}
```

was functionally equivalent to:

```
for(my $i=0; $i<=$#arr; $i++){..}
```

However, in my code there seems to be some slight differences in the way they operate. specifically, the time in which they decide when to terminate. for example:

assume @arr is initialized with one variable in it.

These two blocks should do the same thing right?

```
for my $i (0 .. $#arr)
{
    if(some condition that happens to be true)
    {
        push(@arr, $value);
    } 
}
```

and

```
for (my $i=0; $i<=$#arr; $i++)
{
    if(some condition that happens to be true)
    {
        push(@arr, $value);
    } 
}
```

In execution however, even though a new value gets pushed in both cases, the first loop will stop after only one iteration.

Is this supposed to happen? if so why?

**EDIT:** Thank you for all of your answers, I am aware I can accomplish the same thing with other looping mechanisms. when I asked if there was a another syntax, I was specifically talking about using for. Obviously there isn't. as the syntax to do what I want is already achieved with the c style. I was only asking because I was told to avoid the c style but i still like my for loops.

Comment: Is there another mechanism I can use(besides the c-style) that evaluates after each itteration?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175022/what-am-i-not-getting-about-foreach-loops

Comment: yes, definitely related, but not a duplicate. The other guy didn't realize that when using a foreach, the $_ variable refers to the actual string and not the index. my question was different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`$i<=$#arr` is evaluated before each loop while `(0 .. $#arr)` is evaluated once before any loop.

As such, the first code doesn't "see" the changes to the `@arr` size.

Comment: Is there another syntax I can use that would force the evaluation after each iteration? (besides using c-style)

Comment: @LukeP, There are inifinite number of other ways. Maybe if you told us what about C-style for you were trying to avoid.

Comment: A `for` loop is saying _I am going to do this `X` times no matter what. The problem with _C Style For Loops_ is that this isn't true. They're merely a `while` loop in `for` loop clothing. If you need to change the way you're looping, you should really make it a `while` loop, so people know it. (By the way, this doesn't include `last` which is really just a _get out of the loop free card_. You can have `for` loops with `last` statements.)

Answer (score 3):

> Is there another syntax I can use that would force the evaluation after each iteration? (besides using c-style)

```
for (my $i=0; $i<=$#arr; $i++) {
   ...
}
```

is just another way of writing

```
my $i=0;
while ($i<=$#arr) {
   ...
} continue {
   $i++;
}
```

(Except the  scope of `$i` is slightly different.)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be the do-while construct, although it is a little ungainly.

```
my $i;
do {
    push @arr, $value if condition;
} while ( $i++ < @arr );
```

Comment: Yeah, I figured that, thanks.  I'll just stick with my c loops for those tasks. The reason I asked was because I posted some code on another site and got chewed out for using the c loops. They told me to switch to perl style, so I did, only to find out the perl loops didn't work. haha

Comment: @LukeP Sorry for the ear thrashing you had to take.  Yes, perl style loops are almost always preferred, especially when working with iterators and such.  However, if you're going to be modifying the structure that you're looping on, then a `for (;;)` or `while` is what you need.